# Script doesn't work when it is run using '#!/bin/sh'

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script that use shebang : `#!/bin/sh`, but when I run it in my Ubuntu 14.04 terminal, it doesn't work and it says that some lines has unexpected operator.

My friend in MacOSX could run that script using the `#!/bin/sh` shebang.

I tried to change the shebang into `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, and suddenly, the script works!
What happen here actually?

I really hope that I could also run the `!#/bin/sh` shebang, so that I don't need to change each script that I have.

Comment: I recommend you [edit] this to tell us [a] the complete and exact text of the error message, [b] what operating system your friend's computer is running (is it also Ubuntu? or is it Fedora or some other OS?), [c] if possible, can you show us the script? This would facilitate a definitive answer. Also: did you write this script? Is your goal to make it work on both your and your friend's computer, with `#!/bin/sh` as the hashbang line? With more information this can be definitively answered; until then, I believe [muru's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/537672) is the best that can be given.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your friend on another computer probably uses an OS which has `/bin/sh` linked to `/bin/bash`. In Ubuntu (actually, Debian and most Debian derivatives), `/bin/sh` is not linked to `/bin/bash`, but to [`/bin/dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dash), which doesn't support many `bash`-specific features, but is considerably faster.

On Arch Linux:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 28 15:26 /bin/sh -> bash
```

On Ubuntu:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 19  2014 /bin/sh -> dash
```

#### The right thing to do

If you use a shebang, mean it. Since your script contains `bash`-isms, use `/bin/bash` in the shebang. Or write portable, POSIX-compliant code.

You can speed up this process by using the [`checkbashisms`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/checkbashisms.1.html) program mentioned in [this LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/343924/). It's part of the `devscripts` package, so install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

Thus:

```
checkbashisms /path/to/script.sh || sed -i '1 s;/bin/sh;/bin/bash;' /path/to/script.sh
```

You can convert this to a script (say `convert.sh`):

```
#! /bin/sh

for i
do
    checkbashisms "$i"
    if [ $? = "1" ]
    then
        sed -i '1 s;/bin/sh;/bin/bash;' "$i"
    fi
done
```

The specific return code of `1` means that `checkbashisms` found a possible `bash`ism, and other return values indicate other problems (file not readable, missing shebang, etc.), so we can check for that particular return value.

And then call it with:

```
./convert.sh /path/to/first/script.sh /path/to/second/script.sh
# or 
./convert.sh *.sh
# or
find . -iname '*.sh' -exec ./convert.sh {} +
```

#### The wrong thing to do

Replace `/bin/sh` with a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`.

Recommended reading:

- [Bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) - compares `bash` and `dash` syntax and shows changes needed.
- [Dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) - similar.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 and as you said, when I run `ls -l /bin/sh` it shows that my `/bin/sh -> dash`
So, is there no other solution for me if I don't want to update the script one by one?

Comment: The "wrong thing to do" is one solution, and another is to replace calls to the script with `bash /path/to/script`.

Comment: you can simply wright a small script to change the shebang(s) :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm how can I do that? do you mind to give me an example?

Comment: @blinker check the updated answer.

Comment: @muru one question for you, when I change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, will it cause a problem for the others who has a compatibility with `#!/bin/sh` ? I ask this because this script is not only being used by me.

Comment: @blinker that depends on the script. But usually, no. If the script ran correctly for you with `bash`, it should run correctly for others with `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the export of `IFS` variable definition in ~/.bashrc (~/.profile)

```
#Loop over filenames with spaces
export IFS=$'\n'
```

When changed to either
`export IFS=$' \t\n'  #default according to man dash`
or
`IFS=$'\n'`
#!/bin/sh scripts started working again. In the latter case the definition no longer propagates to forked /bin/sh processes. The meaning of IFS is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting) and setting it to '\n' causes problems in scripts interpreted by **dash** shell, which may be the default shell `/bin/sh -> dash` linked to in your distribution (e.g. debian).